# passing database connection as a method argument

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

There is a web application and a jar application.I am creating a connection object in the web app and passing it to the jar's class as a method argument and trying to execute a stored procedure based on that passed connection in jar.

But the execution of the stored proc halts when its come to     callStmt.executeUpdate()

Can you please put some light on it where I am making mistakes?

Thanks

more addition --

1. I am not getting any exception.It just halts.
2. in web app i am doing this- 
   `jar_common_class().deductMoney(Id,paidAmt,vle,cardno,pin,username,Service ,connection ,"");`
3. then in jar i am doing this - 
   `public String[] deductMoney(String ID, double amount, String uni, String cardNo, String pin, String username, String service, Connection externalCon, String aff)`

Comment: you will need to provide us with details: what exception do you get ? show us the (relevant) code. Further what do you mean with "the jar's class" , what jar ? some external library something you jarred yourself ?Details make people understand your problem !

Comment: 1. I am not getting any exception.It just halts. 2. in web app i am doing this-    jar_common_class().deductMoney(Id,paidAmt,vle,cardno,pin,username,Service ,connection ,""); 3. then in jar i am doing this -    public String[] deductMoney(String ID, double amount, String uni, 
                                String cardNo, String pin, 
                                String username, String service, 
                                Connection externalCon, 
                                String aff)

Comment: Please put the detail into your original question. You can edit your question :)

Comment: @ofortuna, have you look at the database log to see what's going on with the store procedure?

Answer (score 0):

I'm feeling psychic, so without any info in the question I'm going to rely on experience...

My guess is that the stored proc is updating the same data that the web app is using and the stored proc is trying to get a lock on the target data, but can't because the web app is holding some kind of lock on the data and never lets it go. So the stored proc is just (correctly) waiting for the web app to release its locks.

To test this, call your stored proc java app directly from the command line, then it should halt, and then kill your web app - see if the stored proc then proceeds and completes.

If this *is* the case, look at what kind of locks each app is requesting (eg the isolation level of the web app might be "repeatable read", which would normally be a poor choice) and/or examine when locks are released etc